# as.integer() on an int64 dataframe produces unexpected result

Tags: r, integer, int64

I was reviewing some code and came across this odd result.  If you have a dataframe with one value of type integer and you coerce it to integer you get what I think you would expect:

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(x = as.integer(c(1))) %>% as.integer()

[1] 1
```

But if it's of type int64, you get something weird:

```
library(bit64)

tibble(x = as.integer64(c(1))) %>% as.integer()

[1] 0
```

What gives?  I assume it has something to do with the `int64` class.  But why would I get zero?  Is this just bad error handling?

### Update

OK, there's a hint to what's going on when you call `dput` on the `int64` dataframe:

```
structure(list(x = structure(4.94065645841247e-324, 
                             class = "integer64")), 
          row.names = c(NA, -1L), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So `as.integer()` is rightly converting 4.94065645841247e-324 to zero.  But why is that what's stored in the DF?

Also, to see that this is not a `bit64` issue, I get a very similar structure on the actual df I get back from my database:

```
structure(list(max = structure(2.78554211125295e-320,
                               class = "integer64")),
          class = "data.frame", 
          row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: That `double` is how the integer is being represented in the R object storing the data, like I mentioned below.  The class just help informs r which method to use when you want to convert. In fact the DBI documentation mentions `bit64` specifically

Comment: ok, so is `int64` an option in base r?

Comment: No, they’re just using the precision of a double to store more information, allowing for bigger numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a limitation of `bit64`. `bit64` uses the S3 Method `as.integer.integer64` to convert from int64 to int, but only for vectors (unlike base as.integer which can be applied to other objects). The base `as.integer` doesn't know how to convert int64 to int on a data.frame or otherwise.

So after loading `bit64`, `as.integer` will call actually  `as.integer.integer64` on all int64 vectors, but not on a data.frame or tibble.

Comment: There's quite a lot of strange behavior. Look at output of `matrix(as.integer64(x))` for any value of `x`, it's always approximately 0. Considering the documentation mentions these should be usable within vectors, matrices, etc. seems quite strange. I imagine this behavior must be related.

Comment: Agreed. I just tried: `as.vector(as.integer64(1), mode = 'integer')`, which I think is roughly how base as.integer would handle a data.frame. It returns 0

Comment: Looking at the docs, it seems from base R's pov, integer64s are just doubles. as.integer is just converting the integer64's representation as a double in to integer, but that representation is not the actual value.

Comment: Interesting! Good find!

Comment: So I just used `bit64` to make things easier here, but the actual example came out of database without the use of `bit64` I'll update the post.

Comment: I think you're up against the same issue, if you are using `DBI` for example. `as.integer` should work on column mutate since the `.integer64` method will me called, but it would have no way to work on a `data.frame`.

Comment: Check out the update above--this is going on in the structure of the object.

Comment: So, bottom line: should this be considered a "bug" in `bit64`?  You definitely shouldn't get  0 on a dataframe that's int64 when you call `as.integer`.  It should either give you the expected result or throw an error.